# How to configure spring mvc on annotations?

Tags: java, html, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to use spring configuration on annotations. 
To run the application i use tomcat 8.5.50

For this I use

class SpringRootConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.demo")
public class SpringRootConfig {
}
```

i want to use ViewResolver in class SpringWebConfig and i implements WebMvcConfigurer.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.demo.controller")
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setSuffix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setPrefix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.demo.models");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("url");
        dataSource.setUsername("login");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        return dataSource;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

and i use WebDesc. Also i extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer like this

```
public class WebDesc extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(SpringRootConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));


        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        applicationContext.register(SpringWebConfig.class);

        DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = new DispatcherServlet(applicationContext);
        dispatcherServlet.setThrowExceptionIfNoHandlerFound(true);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", dispatcherServlet);

        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encoding-filter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[]{SpringRootConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] {SpringWebConfig.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[0];
    }
}
```

But I get such an error
[image]

What should I do to make the page load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code this way.

it's my SpringWebConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.demo.controller")
public class SpringWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();

        bean.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        bean.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.demo.models");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource restDataSource() {
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/java_a_from_z");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("root");
        return dataSource;
    }

    Properties hibernateProperties() {
        return new Properties() {
            {
                setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
                setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect");
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(
            SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

and WebDesc:

```
public class WebDesc implements WebApplicationInitializer {
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext root =
                new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();

        root.scan("com.demo");
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(root));

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic appServlet =
                servletContext.addServlet("mvc", new DispatcherServlet(new GenericWebApplicationContext()));
        appServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        appServlet.addMapping("/");

        FilterRegistration.Dynamic encodingFilter = servletContext.addFilter("encoding-filter", new CharacterEncodingFilter());
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
        encodingFilter.setInitParameter("forceEncoding", "true");
        encodingFilter.addMappingForUrlPatterns(null, true, "/*");

    }
}
```

Everthing works!